# CORS issue with canvas only when image is preloaded

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, digital-ocean

My issue only arises when the loaded image was preloaded somewhere else. For example, when I somewhere use a `<img>`-tag with the `src` attribute.

Have a look at this code:

```html
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" ></canvas>
 
 <img src="https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg" width="50"/>
 
 <button onclick="show()">Load Canvas Picture</button>
 
 <script>
function show() {
   const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    const img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');


    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 300, 150);
    };
  
    img.src = "https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg"
   
}
</script>
```

*Note: If you are seeing the image in canvas correctly, please cache+hardreload your browser to see the error.*

If you are clicking on the button and open your console, you will see that you are getting a CORS-error:

> Access to image at
>   'https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Now let's take the next example to see that it is working without preloading the image: https://jsfiddle.net/akzxp9vs/

*Note: To make this example work, it's super important that you are deleting your cache + hard reload your browser.*

Only then you see that the correct header response is giving back.

Any ideas what I can do?

The image is on the S3 Cloud of Digital Ocean, called Spaces. The image itself is set to public and the CORS setting are set to:

[image]

Comment: The CORS settings are apparently not working. Try with `curl -i https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg` or with Postman or whatever. There is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker — `curl -H "Origin: http://example.com/"  -i https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg`

Comment: @sideshowbarker the weird part is, that the response header is set correctly in the second example...

Comment: @RolandStarke that bothers me as well! I used to remove the crossOrigin but then when I'm trying to get the blob file of the image, I'm getting the error: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: Shadrix yeah I was testing incorrectly, as @Quentin pointed out. The server expects to see an Origin header, and if it doesn’t see one, it doesn’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response. If the request includes an Origin header, the response will have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as expected. Anyway, see @Quentin’s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser needs to know to check for CORS permissions when the HTTP request is made (i.e. to include an `Origin` header etc).

When you create a new `Image` object, it uses the cached data from the `<img>` element.

Add a [`crossorigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) attribute to the existing `<img>` element or remove that `<img>` element entirely.

Comment: Hmm so are you saying I need to add crossorigin to all my `<img>`tags through my whole page?

Comment: @Shadrix — Only the ones which you want to use with canvas.

Comment: I opened up a new question. I thought the CORS fun is over, but it's not. Perhaps you can have a look on [there as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524534/vue-cors-issue-vue-loads-the-image-a-second-time-but-with-no-cors)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution to my problem. @Quentin's solution is principally right, but it's just not practicable. I tried to update all `<img>`-tags, however in my page I have dozens of packages that are using the `<img>`-tag as well.

For example Leaflet. It's like Google Maps, but with Open Street Maps. You just don't have the control over to set attributes like `crossorigin` in custom icons.

So there had to be another solution. It feels bad to use it, but it does the job.

```
const src = new URL(imgUrl);
src.searchParams.append('cors', Date.now());
return src.href;
```

This code appends to your URL a query parameter and forces Chrome to reload the image without being cached.