# Vue: CORS issue. Vue loads the image a second time but with "no-cors"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors

The underlying problem with CORS was solved in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523575/cors-issue-with-canvas-only-when-image-is-preloaded/58523678?noredirect=1#comment103372920_58523678), however now I'm starting to test it in Vue and I still have CORS issues.

Please have a look at this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/xodk3h9u/

*Note: If you are seeing the image in canvas correctly or the image unloaded, please cache+hardreload your browser to see the error or the image.*

If you are clicking on the button and open your console, you will see that you are getting a CORS-error:

> Access to image at
>   'https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The current issue is, that Vue is somehow loading two requests to the preloaded image. The first one with `cors`, the second one with `no-cors`. Later leads to the wrong caching of the image. Thus, clicking on the button leads to the error.

Why is Vue loading the image for a second round?

[image]

Comment: Super weird. I tested it out with the code snippet of stackoverflow and there it worked perfectly. However, on my server and localhost + JSFiddle, it's not working. So please still have a look on it. In the meantime, I'm looking at older Vue versions. Maybe the problem is found there.

Answer (score 0):

seems preflight request is blocking resources, from other domain

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Not really sure, what should I do then?

Comment: Check with allow-origin :*   header with the server